# My SQL query is returning duplicate results

Tags: php, sql

I have an annoying problem that I cannot get past.

I have a photograph database broken up into two tables:

- Table 1 (`snaps`) consists of four columns:

  ```
    'photoid', 'filename', 'location', 'created'
  ```
- Table 2 (`befter`) which displays the photos in pairs consists of

  ```
    'ppairid', 'beforeid', 'afterid', 'description'
  ```

Table 2 displays the photo pairs, as beforeid and afterid use the unique photoid INT from table 1. All quite simple it would seem.

BUT one of the queries  that I have come up with (by location) duplicates if the location of beforeid and afterid are the same. So for example:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM befter, snaps 
WHERE (snaps.photoid = befter.beforeid OR snaps.photoid = befter.afterid) 
  AND snaps.location = 'oxford'
```

is fine when the photo location is different but not if they're the same. I've tried adding DISTINCT etc but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas please?
P

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in fiddle? https://www.db-fiddle.com

Comment: I tried but i'm getting an error

Comment: Post sample data and expected results in tabular text format.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two `left join`s:

```
select b.*, sb.*, sa.*
from befter b left join
     snaps sb
     on sb.photoid = b.beforeid and sb.location = 'oxford' left join
     snaps sa
     on sa.photoid = b.afterid and sa.location = 'oxford' 
where sb.photoid is not null or sa.photoid is not null;
```

This includes both the before and after snaps in the result set.

Comment: One more question - what are b.*, sb.* and sa.* ?

Comment: @pluto44 . . . Just ways to say "pull the columns that you need".

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the SQL statement what you are fetching from the given tables. If you take an * on two tables, then you will get duplicate results.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
  snaps.photoid, snaps.filename, snaps.location, snaps.created, befter.ppairid, 
  befter.beforeid, befter.afterid, befter.description 
FROM 
  befter
INNER JOIN
  snaps
ON
  snaps.photoid = befter.ppairid
WHERE 
  snaps.location='oxford'
AND
  (snaps.photoid = befter.beforeid OR snaps.photoid = befter.afterid)
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I still get a duplicate on this query as both photos have the location 'Oxford'

Comment: Thanks - but this time it returned no records

Comment: I also tried SELECT * FROM ....... from above and got same answer